# The operator | is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, void

Tags: java, android

Hi i just keep getting that error and im kind of a newbie and dont know wahats going on. Thanks for the help in advance

```
            if(txtvi1.getText().toString().equals("") | txtvi2.getText().toString().equals("") | txtvi3.getText().toString().equals("") | txtvi4.getText().toString().equals("")| txtvi5.getText().toString().equals("") | txtvi6.getText().toString().equals("") | txtvi7.getText().toString().equals("") | txtvi8.getText().toString().equals("") |  checkbx1.setChecked(false)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  string, 5000).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string2, 5000).show();
                }
```

So the error is in the checkbox i just want the toast to appear if any of the textview are empty or if the checkbox is unchecked.
If it is possible how can i do it?

Comment: `checkbx1.setChecked(false)` returns `void`.

Comment: And you generally should use `||` rather than `|` for compound conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use isChecked() function to check whether it is checked or nor.

```
 if(txtvi1.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi2.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi3.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi4.getText().toString().equals("")|| txtvi5.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi6.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi7.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi8.getText().toString().equals("") ||  !checkbx1.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  string, 5000).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string2, 5000).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have written a single pipe sign | for OR condition, which is wrong.

When you need to use `AND` or `OR` conditional operator in `if` condition, they should be like as `AND` = `&&` and `OR` = `||`

so your code needs to be updated as follows,

```
if( txtvi1.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi2.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi3.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi4.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi5.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi6.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi7.getText().toString().equals("") || txtvi8.getText().toString().equals("") ||  !checkbx1.isChecked() ) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  string, 5000).show();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string2, 5000).show();
                }
```

Comment: if i did that edit, then it would called a copied answer,so i didn't. However Thanks for it @AgarwalShankar

Comment: As a side note for the author, the | is a bitwise arithmetic operation.  Consider the two numbers:   int x = 10; int y=6;  Now, their binary representations (i'll keep it to 4 bits for this example) are:  1010 and 0110, respectively.  x | y will bitwise OR, which means that any bit which is on in either number will be on in the result.  So in this example, the resulting binary:  1110 which is the int value 14.

Comment: is that mean you can use | instead of || in if condition, and will going to result same @Matt